# Match string between “img” tag and “alt” tag and line numbers

Tags: php, regex, dom

I am trying to get string between end of “img” tag and closing “a” tag (hello i am from after img tag) from the line below.

```
<a href="products.html><img src="image.jpg"  alt="alt value">hello i am from after img tag</a>
```

And then check to see do they match.At the same time I want to find out the number of that line.
I have tried the following code which gives me line numbers and line of a webpage.

```
        $dom = new domDocument;
        $dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.google.com');
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $new = htmlspecialchars($dom->saveHTML(), ENT_QUOTES);
        $lines = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $new);
        foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {
         echo $lineNumber . \r\r. $line;
        }
```

The following code gives me the image source and alt tag. I can’t get the line number or the text between end of “img” tag and closing “a” tag (hello i am from after img tag).

```
$alts = array();
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $alts[$tag->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->nodeValue] 
            = $tag->attributes->getNamedItem('alt')->nodeValue;
}
foreach($alts as $key => $alt) {
    echo "{$key} => {$alt}<br/>";
}
```

I know regexp is not for html parsing but I tried that as well to see does it work for the following line. 
    $alt = 'hello i am from after img
    tag'
The regexp I have is,
//anything inside alt

```
preg_match_all('|\s*alt[^>]*=[\'"](.*?)[\'"]|i', $alt, $altTag);
```

//anything  between end of “img” tag and closing “a” tag.

```
preg_match_all("#<\s*a[^>]*><\s*img[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*a>#s", $alt, $foo);
```

it works perfect this way but when tried to use the same regExp on variable $line(from the code above)then it does not give me anything.
Can anyone please help me. I really need to make this work. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
$str = '<a href="products.html><img src="image.jpg"  alt="alt value">hello i am from after img tag</a>';
preg_match_all('#<a[^>]+>(.*)</a>#isU', $str, $match);
$result = array_map('strip_tags', $match[1]);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: thanks but regexp i have it works perfect for single string that you have mentioned there. It does not work for the variable $line($line variable is from the example i put up at the top)

Comment: But you can do it without DOMdocument, like this
preg_match_all('#<a[^>]+>(.*)</a>#isU', file_get_contents('http://www.google.com'), $matches);
$matches = array_map('strip_tags', $matches[1]);
print_r($matches[1]);

Answer (score 2):

Using Regexp in you case is not a good idea but if you really want to use it then you need to change your foreach loop. here is the code.

```
foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $l){ 
$line= html_entity_decode($l);
}
```

Now you can apply regExp to find what you want.